# Issue with HttpClient since Xamarin Froms 4.5.0.356

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had to update my xamarin forms version from 4.3.0947036 to 4.5 or higher because of [UIWebView Deprecation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/) in IOS. The problem is that one of my HttplClient Rest calls which worked perfectly with the previous version (4.3.0947036), does not anymore, and the weird thing is that I test that REST call in my browser and works good, I even test it with RestClient library and the result is the same, I get code 0 in my browser (which is correct) and in my app an exception is shown with the message:

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Just for the record, I've tried with newer versions of xamarin forms and still crashes, the last version I tested was 4.6.0.72.

Comment: if you're getting an exception, what does the stack trace show?

Comment: Wel @Jason, all i get is the loading of the data in my visual object, but it does not show any information about the REST call, so i will make some tests using another visual object (Treeview).

Comment: @Jason, thanks for your help but i noticed that the problem was a bad manage of the mainthread within my app, so while one process hadn't finshed, another one was consuming the result of the last one, i fixed it and had nothing to do with HttpClient or my visual controls :)